# exporting to .3ds changes the scale

Tags: export

I have a .3ds file someone gave me that will load in fine. I will edit it a little bit, just translating so i can change the point of origin, I export as .3ds again. If I reload it, it will be far smaller.

Is there a setting somewhere that decides what scale to maintain when it exports an object?

Comment: This is known behavior

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise should I just increase the scale on my models? does it change the scale randomly or is the scale value known? looks just less than a 1/3

Comment: It should be constant, generally it is caused by incompatibilities of the measurement system, which should stay the same.

Comment: is there anyway to set that in an export setting?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. It should be implemented, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the 3ds import has an option for size constraint that controls the model scale while importing, setting it to zero should stop the scaling from happening.

[image]

Comment: works like a charm, just what i was after, thanks.